# Maven generatePackage for a wsdl generating classes from schema definition

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl, pom.xml

I am using Java14 with SpringBoot.

I need to generate some Java classes based on a wsdl. It is generating, however, it puts all the generated classes in a flat structure and not in the packages specified in the wsdl.

If anyone can give some advise, I would appreciate it.

**More details:**

POM (you can see that the generated package is `com.travellinck.client.approval`)

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.travellinck.client.approval</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

WSDL

```
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.5-b05 .  -->
<!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.5-b05 .  -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" name="ApprovalService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation/strategy" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=2"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=3"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/contact" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=4"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=5"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="submitRequestForApproval">
        <part xmlns:ns1="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="approvalRequest" element="ns1:approvalRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="submitRequestForApprovalResponse">
        <part xmlns:ns2="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="approvalResponse" element="ns2:approvalResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:unsupportedBusinessRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:unsupportedSupportingDocument"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getApprovalState">
        <part xmlns:ns3="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="getApprovalStateRequest" element="ns3:getApprovalStateRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getApprovalStateResponse">
        <part xmlns:ns4="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="getApprovalStateResponse" element="ns4:getApprovalStateResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:unknownApprovalRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
        <part xmlns:ns5="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="withdrawApprovalRequest" element="ns5:withdrawApprovalRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse">
        <part xmlns:ns6="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="withdrawApprovalResponse" element="ns6:withdrawApprovalResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="InvalidRequest">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:invalidRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="RequestNoLongerInProgress">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:requestNoLongerInProgress"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="Approval">
        <operation name="submitRequestForApproval">
            <input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApprovalRequest" message="tns:submitRequestForApproval"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApprovalResponse" message="tns:submitRequestForApprovalResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:UnsupportedBusinessRequest" name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApproval/Fault/UnsupportedBusinessRequest"/>
            <fault message="tns:UnsupportedSupportingDocument" name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApproval/Fault/UnsupportedSupportingDocument"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getApprovalState">
            <input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalStateRequest" message="tns:getApprovalState"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalStateResponse" message="tns:getApprovalStateResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:UnknownApprovalRequest" name="UnknownApprovalRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalState/Fault/UnknownApprovalRequest"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
            <input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApprovalRequest" message="tns:withdrawRequestForApproval"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse" message="tns:withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:InvalidRequest" name="InvalidRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/InvalidRequest"/>
            <fault message="tns:RequestNoLongerInProgress" name="RequestNoLongerInProgress" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/RequestNoLongerInProgress"/>
            <fault message="tns:UnknownApprovalRequest" name="UnknownApprovalRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/UnknownApprovalRequest"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="ApprovalPortBinding" type="tns:Approval">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="submitRequestForApproval">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest">
                <soap:fault name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument">
                <soap:fault name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getApprovalState">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
                <soap:fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="InvalidRequest">
                <soap:fault name="InvalidRequest" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="RequestNoLongerInProgress">
                <soap:fault name="RequestNoLongerInProgress" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
                <soap:fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="ApprovalService">
        <port name="ApprovalPort" binding="tns:ApprovalPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8088/approval"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

This generates the model classes in the `com.travellinck.client.approval` package.

[image]

This is incorrect, I would expect it to rather generate them as follows (This was taken from another application using Java7 that generated the model classes from the same wsdl):

[image]

As you can see, these classes are not in a flat structure, but rather in their packages according to the wsdl definition:

e.g.

```
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/contact" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=4"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

It's as if it is ignoring the `/contact`.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by rather using apache.cxf

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/approval.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```